# My application is crashing without showing any error in logcat

Tags: android-studio

please mention the issue in my code. I've used a seekbar. On click of that it crashes straight away. i've used reset button also below the seekbar and I kept onstart tracking touch and onstop tracking touch empty.

```
val initialTextViewTranslationY = textView_progress.translationY
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
            textView_progress.text = progress.toString()
            val translationdistance = (initialTextViewTranslationY + progress * resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_anim_step) * -1)
            textView_progress.animate().translationY(translationdistance)
            if (!fromUser)
                textView_progress.animate().setDuration(500).rotationBy(360f).translationY(initialTextViewTranslationY)

        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
```

It generates the logcat as follows.

```
at android.widget.SeekBar.onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:113)
    at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.startDrag(AbsSeekBar.java:1299)
    at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:1238)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2469)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:623)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1909)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3247)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:585)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11165)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5227)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5076)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4633)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4599)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4736)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4793)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4633)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4599)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4580)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7210)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7142)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7103)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `TODO(...)` invocations.

It's a Kotlin function that throws an exception at runtime:

source:

```
/**
 * Always throws [NotImplementedError] stating that operation is not implemented.
 *
 * @param reason a string explaining why the implementation is missing.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun TODO(reason: String): Nothing = throw NotImplementedError("An operation is not implemented: $reason")
```